# Error in simple makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am getting an error here. It should work

Error:

```
make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 1: Extra `:', `::', or `:=' on dependency line
```

Makefile:

```
warmup1: cs402.o my402list.o
    gcc -o warmup1 -g cs402.o my402list.o

cs402.o: cs402.c my402list.h
    gcc -g -c -Wall cs402.c

my402list.o: my402list.c my402list.h
    gcc -g -c -Wall my402list.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o warmup1
```

env

```
USER=zzz
LOGNAME=zzz
HOME=/home/scf-16/zzz
PATH=/usr/lsd/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/sbin
MAIL=/var/mail/zzz
SHELL=/bin/tcsh
TZ=US/Pacific
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/100
TERM=xterm
KRB5CCNAME=FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_193236
HOSTTYPE=sun4
VENDOR=sun
OSTYPE=solaris
MACHTYPE=sparc
SHLVL=1
PWD=/home/scf-16/zzz
GROUP=cscs-maj
```

I have tried everything.

Where am i going wrong? is the problem due to PATH?

Comment: The indentation on dependency lines is TABs, not four spaces, right?

Comment: That makefile looks fine (unless you are using spaces instead of tabs).

Comment: Strange... Can you simplify it? Maybe remove the other rules, and make the command a simple `echo hello` or something? Maybe remove one of the prerequisites? Or both?...

Comment: Wait... what version of Make?

Comment: I did try removing rules. same error

Comment: how do i check the version?

Comment: "which make", will show which "make" program is called. "make -v" should show you the version of make. Note: I think you asked this question before ? I tried your makefile by copying. There is no error in this makefile (it works ok). So it has to be something else (not related to the content of the makefile...)

Comment: Just saw: You are running on Solaris on a sparc ?! I do not even know what kind of "make" you have here...

Comment: And one more: Do you have "gmake" on your machine ? maybe try with "gmake" instead of "make" (no clue what the solaris make does...)

Comment: Note: you can find the solaris make docu here: (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9l0/index.html)

Comment: yes i had asked this before. It didnt run on my local. now uploaded to server. Make -v gave this warning
make: Warning: Ignoring DistributedMake -v option

Comment: `ls /usr/sfw/bin/make`  or `ls /usr/sfw/bin/gmake`   -- try both commands.  Substitute the one that you find for your make command.  Those are the two file names you will see for **GNU make**.

Comment: Maybe line break encoding is messed up.  Maybe Make is not considering the linebreaks in the file.

Comment: @kanishka , what is File here in one of you variables ? `KRB5CCNAME=FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_193236`  , if you comment that does the make command still give error : test it with make -n (no execution)